# What is happening behind .setAttribute vs .attribute=?

Tags: javascript

**Description:**

I am using simple `javascript` to set a the value of an `input`. I am using multiple methods that appear to be the same but with different results. Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="testinput" value="" type="text" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
var input = document.getElementByTagName('input')[0];
input.value = "5"

console.log(input.value) // returns "5"
console.log(input.getAttribute("value")) // returns ""
```

Of course the functionality is reversed when using the `setAttribute()` function. Yet, when on form submit they both give a `input=5` result.

**Question:**

What is the point of separating the two properties? is the `.value` stored differently than the `.getAttribute("value")`?

**Disclaimer:**

I have read:

- [When to use setAttribute vs .attribute= in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)
- [Setting a property via property or setAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018814/setting-a-property-via-property-or-setattribute)

Both of those question/answers left me confused and unsatisfied.

Comment: see also [Properties and Attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6003819/1048572)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`input.value` is dot notation, it sets the `value` ***property*** of the input object.

It does in no way update any attributes, so trying to get an attribute with the same name will ***not*** return the updated value.

If for some reason you have to update the attribute, you would do

```
input.setAttribute('value', 'new_value');
```

but you shouldn't have to use that, as you generally should be working with the properties, not the attributes, and you'd set and get the `value` property, not the attribute.

---

An attribute in HTML is a key / value pair inside the opening and closing brackets, as in

```
<div attribute="attribute_value"></div>
```

In many cases such attributes will set the initial value of the underlying property, and the property is a named key with a value, that is attached to the internal model of an element, which is what we access with javascript, the object holding the model and data for the element.

Changing any of that objects keys or values does not change the HTML, only the internal representation of the element, the object. However, changing the HTML attributes will in some cases change the object representation of the element.

`getAttribute` gets the actual attributes from the HTML, not the properties, while `element.value` clearly accesses a named property in the object representing that element.

Comment: Your edit is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't separating the internal object with the html object.

Comment: @Phil - Attributes and properties can be hard to grok, and in many cases they seem like the same thing as they are so tightly bound together, but they really are two different things, and as shown they can have different names and values even if they seem to represent the same thing.

Comment: Follow up question, if I use `document.createElement()` add a attribute to that and `append()` it to the page, would that be treated like an `html` object or would it just be an internal object?

Comment: If you add an attribute, as in use setAttribute, it's treated as a HTML attribute, but if you set the property, it's on the internal object. You can just test it out, see this -> http://jsfiddle.net/9VfyE/

Comment: I like the explanation above. May I add that MDN's documentation backs this up with encouragement to use properties instead of .attribute or setAttribute() whenever applicable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: "Changing any of that objects keys or values does not change the HTML" - not quite; setting `input.defaultValue = 'blah';` changes the HTML representation of that element.

Answer (score 15):

It's important to take note of the differences between attributes and properties.

#### The `value` attribute

The `value` attribute of an `<input>`, visible in the HTML representation of the element, is mapped to the `defaultValue` *property*. For example:

```
var i = document.createElement('input');
i.setAttribute('value', 'foo');
console.log(i.defaultValue, i.getAttribute('value')); // "foo foo"

i.defaultValue = 'bar';
console.log(i.defaultValue, i.getAttribute('value')); // "bar bar"
```

#### The `value` property

The `value` property mirrors the `defaultValue` property (and `value` attribute) until it's explicitly been given a value, so:

```
var i = document.createElement('input');
i.defaultValue = 'foo';
console.log(i.value); // "foo"

i.value = 'bar';
i.defaultValue = 'foo';
console.log(i.value); // "bar"
```

This is another way of looking at it:

```
<input value="foo">
       ↑↓
input.defaultValue = "foo";
        ↓
input.value
  get(): value === undefined ? input.defaultValue : value
  set(newValue): value := newValue
```

#### Anchors

When using anchors, the `href` attribute and `href` property update each other, but in a different way, e.g.:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', '/test');
console.log(a.href); // "http://stackoverflow.com/test"

a.href = '/test';
console.log(a.getAttribute('href')); // "/test"
```

#### Other elements

Here's a (partial) list of attributes and their corresponding properties:

```
element  | attribute | property
---------+-----------+----------------
option   | selected  | defaultSelected (bool)
label    | for       | htmlFor
input    | checked   | defaultChecked (bool)
select   | multiple  | multiple (bool)
li       | value     | value (int)
```

As you can see, whereas the attributes are always strings, the corresponding properties may be of other types.

Comment: very well explained. and I didn't know there was a progression of assignments. very cool and thank you!

Comment: @Phil Actually, I didn't explain it well enough .. updated the answer :)

Comment: This is interesting to read! Interestingly, last week I had some code which was setting `.value` for an `li` element created with `createElement`. The `value` attribute was correctly set... but the value was being parsed as an integer! When I switched to `setAttribute`, the problem disappeared. (The value fields were GUIDs pulled from a database.) I don't have the code any more as that was prototyping some functionality; now my attributes are being bound with knockout.js, but the revelation was surprising.

Comment: @BrianS Right, because the `value` is used in conjunction with `<ol>` to indicate what number the bullet point should have :) funny