# How to detect when the value of an input changes dynamically with JS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, dynamic, triggers

I am able to detect if an input changes value while typing, pasting, etc, But if the value changed dynamically from another script I am unable to detect it:

Lets say I have an input

```
<input id="testInput" value="Type Here" />
```

And if the value changes by typing on it I want to alert "changed"

```
$('#testInput').on('input', function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

This works, but if the value changed dynamically from another script, I can't trigger the alert:

```
$('#testInput').val("Dynamic Value"); //This doesn't show the alert
```

I want to be able to detect if the value changed at all, either by typing, pasting, or dynamically from a script or action.

`.val()` Is beeing executed in many different places, so changing `.val()` all over the code for something else like `.val().trigger("change")` is not an option.

Here is a jsfiddle with a better example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/486146/

Comment: `input paste keyup change` `===` `input`

Comment: @Ele, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635867/4875631

Comment: @FrankerZ There are many places where .val() might be executed, I don't want to go change every single .val(), I just want to detect when it is executed, thanks

Comment: @multimediaxp That isn't changing every `.val()`. That's overridding the main `.val()` function in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is overriding the function `$.fn.val()`

*This is a basic approach to start with.*

```js
var $val = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function(newVal) {
  if (this.attr('id') === 'target') this.trigger('input');
  $val.call(this, newVal);
}

$('#target').on('input', function() {
  alert("changed");
});

$('#target').val('Ele from Stack');
$('#target2').val('Ele from Stack2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='target' />
<input id='target2' />
```

Comment: Nice, but this affects any other val() across the script, Thanks this is a solution, but is there a cleaner way? Thanks

Comment: @multimediaxp check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383745/5665870](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383745/5665870)

Answer (score 4):

Just trigger the event!

```
$('#testInput').val("Dynamic Value").trigger("input");
```

Comment: There are many places where .val() might be executed, I don't want to go change every single .val(), I just want to detect when it is executed

Answer (score 2):

Inpired of [Ele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715121/ele)'s answer...

While overriding the `.val()` function... Instead of comparing the id, you could add an agrument for the even to trigger! If it's not provided, there is no change from the "regular" `.val()` function. If provided, it triggers the event.

You will have to change every places where the value is programmatically changed anyway, but in a more practical way. ;)

```js
var $val = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function(newVal,eventToTrigger) {
  if (eventToTrigger != null) this.trigger(eventToTrigger);
  $val.call(this, newVal);
}

$('.someClass').on('input', function() {
  alert("Programmatically inputted!");
});

$('.otherClass').on('change', function() {
  alert("Programmatically changed!");
});

$('.someClass').val('Hello you!','input');
$('.otherClass').val('Doing fine?','change');
$('#whatever').val('Hehehe.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="someClass">
<input type="text" class="otherClass">
<input type="text" id="whatever">
```

Comment: Yes this sample code worked for me, thanks you very much ;)