# How can I respond to an input element's value property being set?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm writing a [user script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) which needs to respond to an `<input>` element's value changing, no matter how the change was made.

For user interactions, this is easy — just add a listener for the `input` event. However, I haven't yet found a way to respond to the input's value being set directly by changing its `.value` property.

I've tried adding listeners for the `change` and `input` events (neither are triggered) and adding a `MutationObserver` for both the input's attributes and the input's parent's child list (again, neither are triggered). There also doesn't appear to be a property descriptor I can modify.

How can I trigger code to run when an `<input>` element's `.value` property is set?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Detect value change</title>

    <script type="module">
      const range = document.querySelector('input');

      range.addEventListener('change', (event) => console.log('Change:', event));
      range.addEventListener('input', (event) => console.log('Input:', event));

      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => console.log('Mutation:', mutations));

      observer.observe(range, { attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['value'] });
      observer.observe(range.parentNode, { childList: true });

      console.log('Property descriptors:', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(range));

      // Somewhere else, in code I don't control:
      document.querySelector('input').value = 7;
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Console output:

```
Property descriptors: {}
```

Comment: JavaScript does not trigger event listeners. Plenty of questions with solutions. Basically if you can not alter the code that sets it, you basically need to use a settimeout and listen for the change because MutationObserver looks for DOM changes and value change does not trigger it. Value is a property, not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Fire the change event after updating the value programmatically:

```
range.value = 7;
var event = new Event('change');
range.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: I don't have control over how the page sets the value. Unless I can respond to it being set via `.value`, I can't run code when it's set.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383745/1589521) for great information on why `MutationObserver` will not catch modifications to properties.

If you are unable to modify the way the value is being changed (`node.setAttribute('value', 'newValue')` would fire your `MutationObserver`, for example), then I think your only option is unfortunately a `setInterval` that poles for value changes at a set frequency.

Something like this:

```js
const range = document.querySelector('input');

document.getElementById('incrementValue').addEventListener('click', () => {
 const val = range.valueAsNumber;
 range.value = range.value === range.max ? range.min : String(val + 1);
});

let currentVal;
setInterval(() => {
 // Check for val changes every 1sec
 if (range.value === currentVal) {
  return;
 }
 currentVal = range.value;
 console.log(`New value detected. New value is ${range.value}`);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Detect value change</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="incrementValue">Increment value</button>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't really expect the `MutationObserver` to work, but it seemed worth a shot, since some properties *do* trigger it (such as `document.title`) and there's a `value=` attribute. (Though the attribute and the property have different meanings, so no surprise that it didn't work.)