# Angular how to observe DOM elements property change?

Tags: angular, dom, properties, observable

I am trying to make a directive which listens for `DOM property changes` to automatically save a property value to LocalStorage, and restore it automatically on page load (to save user preferences on any HTML element). I need it to listen to input changes, but since I want a generic directive, I don't want to listen to the `change` event.

I got a solution working using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55737231/7920723

I had to convert it to typescript and adapt it to use `Observables`, here is a mvce:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cdltStoreProperty]',
  standalone: true
})
export class StoreAttributeDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  id!: string;

  @Input('cdltStoreProperty') attributeName: string | null = null;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  @Output() readonly storedValue = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
    private ref: ElementRef
  ) {
    console.log('test');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const element = this.ref.nativeElement;
    
    if (this.attributeName) {
      this.id = `${StoreAttributeDirective.name}_${element.getAttribute('id')}`;
      console.log(`id = ${this.id}`);
      
      const valueStored = this.restoreValue();
      if (!valueStored) {
        const value = element[this.attributeName];
        this.saveValue(value);
        this.storedValue.emit(value);
      }
      
      observePropertyChange(this.ref, this.attributeName).subscribe(newValue => {
        console.log("property changed");
        this.saveValue(newValue)
      });
    }
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  restoreValue() : any {
    const valueStored = window.localStorage.getItem(this.id);
    console.log(`valueStored = ${valueStored} of type = ${typeof valueStored}`);

    if (valueStored && this.attributeName) {
      const value = JSON.parse(valueStored);
      console.log(`Restoring value ${value} of type ${typeof value}`);
      this.ref.nativeElement[this.attributeName] = value;
      return value;
    }

    return undefined;
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  saveValue(value: any) {
    console.log(`Saving ${value} of type ${typeof value}`);
    const valueToStore = JSON.stringify(value);
    console.log(`Saving value to store ${valueToStore} of type ${typeof valueToStore}`);
    window.localStorage.setItem(this.id, valueToStore);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'cdlt-mvce',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [StoreAttributeDirective],
  template: `
    <input
      id="remember-me-checkbox"
      type="checkbox"
      cdltStoreProperty="checked"
      [checked]="checkedValue"
      (storedValue)="loadStoredValue($event)"
      (change)="checkedValue = !checkedValue"
>`,
  styleUrl: './mvce.component.scss'
})
export class MvceComponent {
  checkedValue = true;

  loadStoredValue(value: any) {
    this.checkedValue = value;
  }
}

function observePropertyChange(elementRef: ElementRef, propertyName: string) : Observable<any> {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const propertyObserver$ = new Observable<any>(observer => {
    const superProps = Object.getPrototypeOf(elementRef.nativeElement);
    const propertyDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(superProps, propertyName);

    if (!propertyDescriptor) {
      console.error(`No property descriptor for ${propertyName}`);
      return;
    }
    const superGet = propertyDescriptor.get;
    const superSet = propertyDescriptor.set;
    if (!superGet) {
      console.error(`No getter for ${propertyName}`);
      return;
    } else if (!superSet) {
      console.error(`No setter for ${propertyName}`);
      return;
    }

    const newProps = {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      get: function() : any {
        return superGet.apply(this, []);
      },
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      set: function (t : any) : any {
        observer.next(t);
        return superSet.apply(this, [t]);
      }
    };

    Object.defineProperty(elementRef.nativeElement, propertyName, newProps);
  });

  return propertyObserver$;
}
```

Since I'm accessing properties I subscribe to the property during the `AfterViewInit` phase, do you think this is correct ?

There are 2 problems with this code:

- If you refresh while the `input` is unchecked, the restore function raises an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, so I guess this isn't the right way to do this
- If you use an input with the property `checked` not bound, for example with `checked=false`, the observer breaks somewhere, for reasons I don't understand, as if the `nativeElement` or the `checked` property were replaced after the view initialization.

Do you know what would be the correct way to achieve such a directive ?

Comment: It may be better to do this on a property in your model: https://gist.github.com/theredhead/e49ffa7bf85d623d39499a98ada4bc66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I feel a better idea is to do this when a property changes on your viewmodel (or component) instance, it's fairly simple.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/theredhead/e49ffa7bf85d623d39499a98ada4bc66)

```
//
// Inspired by https://github.com/zhaosiyang/property-watch-decorator/blob/master/src/index.ts
//
// Annotate a field in a typescript class to store its' content in localstorage transparently.
//
export function Preference<T = any>(preferenceKey: string, defaultValueObj: T) {
  return (target: any, key: PropertyKey) => {
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      set: function(value) {
        localStorage.setItem(preferenceKey, JSON.stringify(value));
      },
      get: function() {
        const rawValue = window.localStorage.getItem(preferenceKey);
        const value = rawValue !== null && rawValue !== undefined ? <T>JSON.parse(rawValue) : defaultValueObj;
        return value;
      },
    });
  };
}
```

you can then use it in your component:

```
   class PreferencesComponent {
       @Preference('TableView.itemsPerPage', 10)
       itemsPerPage: number;
   }
```

and bind it as normal:

```
   <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="itemsPerPage" min="10" max="100">
```

Hope this helpse!

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I find it very concise and elegant, I'm really not used to using decorators in Typescript but this definitely looks like the way to go ! :)

By the way, you forgot to close the quote of the preference key string in your component example

Comment: @Harkan, I've added the missing quote, likely an incompatibility between my fingers and windows' keyboard settings. Thanks for noting it.