# Trouble getting an item through the JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, console

I am trying to get an element of a page using the Console. Here is the code:

```js
var ELEMENT = document.querySelector('div.flexCenter-3_1bcw.flex-1O1GKY.justifyCenter-3D2jYp.alignCenter-1dQNNs')
```

And I want to get a specific 'thing' from the element:

```js
ELEMENT.__reactProps$81cjqqgfk4j
```

Unfortunately, the `.__reactProps$` 'thing' changes every time I visit the page. Sometimes, it might be `__reactProps$25jwbxmtle` or `__reactProps$94maqnwnty`, and so on. What can I do here?

When I type `ELEMENT.attributes`, this comes up:

```js
NamedNodeMap {0: class, class: class, length: 1}
    0: class
        ownerDocument: document
            .__reactEvents$81cjqqgfk4j
```

The `.__reactEvents` item always ends with the same string as the `.__reactProps` item.

Is there a way to get the name of this item from the attributes? (Because that would be enough for me.)

Comment: Why are you trying to get this internal data? You should likely not be using that at all because it is not deterministically usable

Comment: @Dominik I am trying to automate something on a website. It's completely harmless though

Comment: Don't rely on that attribute. React uses that internally and like I said for your purposes it's nondeterministic.

Comment: Use react to keep track of components. Using vanilla JS like that will break in all sorts of ways

Comment: I haven't been able to find alternatives. Could you please help me regardless?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. You just described a thing you're doing that isn't feasible. Describe what it is that you're actually doing and we can help

Comment: "*Is there a way I can get the name of this item from the attributes*" - no, [it's not an attribute but a DOM property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151560/what-is-happening-behind-setattribute-vs-attribute). Sure, there are ways to enumerate properties as well, but you shouldn't use this approach anyway. React developers made it deliberately hard to access these *internals* by randomising the property name, because you really shouldn't use it. Whatever you're trying to do, this is the wrong way, and you're nudged to use the proper way because it'll be easier.

Comment: Thank you all for the pep talk but that's not what I asked for. I asked somewhere where people are more willing to be helpful and solved the issue. Damn...

Comment: Does the element have an attribute with that name?

Comment: I don't think it was an attribute @user1476072

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys(ELEMENT)` to get all the keys for that element and than search for the needed one. This will extract prefix, the random ID:

```
var ELEMENT = document.querySelector('div.flexCenter-3_1bcw.flex-1O1GKY.justifyCenter-3D2jYp.alignCenter-1dQNNs');

let id = null;
for(let i = 0, keys = Object.keys(ELEMENT); i < keys.length; i++)
{
  if ((id = keys[i].match(/^__react[^$]*(\$.+)$/)))
  {
    id = id[1];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(id);
```