# Force picker view to pop up using Javascript on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

When you touch on a menu item in a web page on the iPhone, a picker view appears that allows you to select from the values that are in the menu.

I have a web page with a menu, but I'm trying to get the picker view to appear programmatically rather than have the user touch it first. This is my form

```
<form id="myForm">
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c" selected>c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I've tried the click() function on "mySelect" and I've tried adding focus first as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mySelect').focus(function() {
$('#mySelect').click();
});
  });
```

but nothing seems to work. I've tried this in Safari without success either, so it probably not webkit-specific.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can't be done. See Rex M's answer to this similar question.

[Display DropDown options on Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932504/display-dropdown-options-on-focus)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is binding an event handler to a `focus` event, which invokes a `click` method on the select field. I'm not sure if that's what you want, I would suggest you try doing it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('#mySelect'); // Cache DOM requests. In this case it might be pointless
                                 // but in other it might help.

    select.trigger('click'); // The trigger method not only triggers event handlers,
                             // but also sends a native DOM event.
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. The menu just sits there waiting for the user to click it. I guess part of my problem is that I don't know what event triggers the appearance of the menu items, let alone whether we can emulate that event in javascript.

Comment: Oh, ok. Maybe it's the `$(document).ready` part that's causing trouble? Have you tried triggering a click right away, without waiting for the DOM to load?